# Implementing removeItem() of single linked list

Tags: java

Below is the `SingleLinkedList` type abstraction implemented in java.

```
 public class SingleLinkedList<T>{

        /**
         * Abstract data type constitutes constructor and selector functions
         * written below under representation that hold below invariant:
         * If a recursive list s is constructed from a first element f and a recursive list r, then
         *    • first(s) returns f, and
         *    • rest(s) returns r, which is a recursive list.
         */


        /**
         * Representation - start
         */

        private static SingleLinkedList<?> emptyList = null;
        private T item;
        private SingleLinkedList<T> restOfTheList;

        /**
         * Constructor
         * @param first
         * @param rest
         */
        public SingleLinkedList(T first, SingleLinkedList<T> rest){
                this.item = first;
                this.restOfTheList = rest;
        }

        /**
         * Selector function
         * @param list
         * @return
         */
        private T first(){
            return this.item;
        }

        /**
         * Selector function
         * @param list
         * @return
         */
        private SingleLinkedList<T> rest(){
            return this.restOfTheList;
        }

        /**
         * Representation - end
         */


        /**
         * User interface - starts
         * These methods must take help of constructor or selector and some helper functions.
         */

        public final int length(){
            return this.lengthOfTheList(0); 
        }

        protected final int lengthOfTheList(int length){
            if(this.rest() == emptyList){
                return length;
            }else{
                return this.rest().lengthOfTheList(length + 1);
            }
        }



        public final T getItem(int position){
            if(position == 1){
                return this.first();
            }else{
                return this.rest().getItem(position - 1);
            }
        }


        public final void removeItem(int position){

        }


        public static void main(String[] args){
            SingleLinkedList<Integer> list = new SingleLinkedList<Integer>(3, new SingleLinkedList<Integer>(2, new SingleLinkedList<Integer>(1, null)));
            list = new SingleLinkedList<Integer>(4, list);
            list.removeItem(3);

        }
    }
```

---

I would need some hint on completing `removeItem()` method.

This work is not part of any homework question.

I am trying to port this python [code](https://github.com/shamhub/CS61A_Fall2012/blob/master/recursive_list.py) to java.

Please help me!!

Comment: *"This work is not part of any homework question."* - that's irrelevant, this still isn't a code-writing or tutorial service.

Comment: You _do_ realize that you try to port code from a functional programming course? Are you sure that you want to make `removeItem` in-place, making your data structure mutable?

Comment: @Carsten Yes I want to make this data structure mutable. Because multiple users would share this same data structure

Comment: @Carsten this is the [code](https://github.com/shamhub/Abstractions/blob/master/JavaCode/src/Sequence.java) for `deleteItem()` now am not getting proper base cases for `insertItem()`

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to remove a **specific** item in the list, you are going to need to keep track of 2 things

1. The node you are looking at
2. The next node from your current position. (You need to check if it's null before operating on it.)

Now, let's think of the logic. Let's say I have a list of the following items:

```
1 -> 3 -> 5 -> 7 -> 9 -> NULL
^              ^          ^
head    item to remove    tail
```

So, if we want to remove 7, we need to make the **next** node of 5 point to 9.

```
1 -> 3 -> 5 -/ 7  -> 9 -> NULL
^         -----------^    ^
head                      tail
```

The cases that *must* be considered when doing this:

- What do you do when removing the head node?
- What do you do when removing the tail node
- What do you do when removing a node between two nodes? (Demonstrated above)

This should be enough of a "hint" to get you started. As always, be thinking of a way to be the "devil's advocate"; what would **break my program**. If you approach the structure in this way, you'll avoid a lot of headaches as you extrapolate your data structure, especially if it is mutable.

Comment: In this context, "tail" refers to all elements except the first, rather than a last terminator element, as it is used in a node based linked list approach.

Comment: @Carsten seems like a very un-intuitive way to implement a linked-list. Why would this approach be preferred over the way I have explained?

(Not saying OP should completely rework, just curious to pros/cons).

Comment: @Carsten 1) Why teachers dictate us to learn/follow node based linked list approach as shown [here](https://github.com/shamhub/Abstractions/blob/master/JavaCode/src/SList.java)? In contrary, the above approach follows the idea like "item and the rest of the list"? the above approach looks more intuitive(or mathematical), right? So, Why teachers start writing `class SListNode{..` ?  2)Do you think the above approach actually allows you to implement operations like insert/delete by maintaining immutability?In node based approach, it is not possible to maintain immutability. Do you feel the same?